# What is the name of the UIView used at the "home" screen of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

First of all, the question is very simple, but I have tried to look around on the Internet and I couldn't find a name for this. Several applications such as "Ping Lite" have used this view in their application. It allows you to have submodules/applications as icons and you can scroll the page around just like when you are at "home" screen.

Can somebody tells me what is the name of the class that is used there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of view is not available in the iPhone SDK. It is written by Apple and it's not included in the UIKit framework. It's only available in SpringBoard.app, the application responsible for many features of the OS (kind of Finder.app).

However, you can write it yourself of course, using a `UIScrollView`. This will take some time but luckily we have the [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20/) project, which implements the [TTLauncherView](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/TTLauncherView.m) class

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the standard sdk has no such a class. You can check third-party libraries(three20, for example) or customize UIScrollView behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The UIView used at the “home” screen of iPhone is a UIScrollView alongwith UIPageControl.

Check the PageControl sample code from Apple and you will learn how it works.